# How to find $h'(x)$ given the following?

Tags: derivatives

I need some help with this since I can't seem to figure it out:

$h(x)= f(2x - g(x))$

How do I simplify this in such a way that if I have several values for $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ and $x$, I can solve for $h'(x)$

```
x  f(x) g(x) f'(x) g'(x)

-1 -1    0    2    -2
 0  0    1    5     4
 1  4    2    3     1
```

Find $h'(1)$

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a general expression $h'(x)$ that you can plug *any* $x$ into? Or simply $h'(x)$ for a specific value of $x$?

Comment: And you should include in the post any values for $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $g'(x)$ that you have been provided.

Comment: A general expression. I have a table which have some values for x and the resulting value for f(x), g(x),f'(x) and g'(x).

Comment: With that information alone, you will only be able to find $h'(x)$ for a handful of values of $x$.

Comment: Can you post what you get as a general expression for $h'(x)$ using the *chain rule*?

Comment: @user153841 I edited the post

Comment: @Tom Post edited

Comment: I would assume the first row of numbers should be for $x=-1$ rather than $x=1$?

Comment: @Hayden Sorry, I fixed it. But how would you know? :)

Comment: @Sabಠ_ಠ Because otherwise you don't have enough information. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to use the chain rule: 
$$h'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(2x-g(x)) \cdot f'(2x-g(x))=(2-g'(x))f'(2x-g(x))$$

If we wish to find $h'(1)$, we start by plugging in $x=1$ to get
$$h'(1)=(2-g'(1))f'(2-g(1))=(2-1)f'(2-2)=f'(0)=5$$

Comment: I see. Thanks. But let's say I wanted to find $f'(2x-g(x))$, is there a way to simplify it further?

Comment: Sadly, without knowing anything more about $f$ and $g$, there's not much that can be said about $f'(2x-g(x))$.

Comment: Okay. I got it now. One last question. How do you know chain rule should be used here and not something else?

Comment: Pretty much whenever you see a composition of functions, it's a good indication that chain rule should be used.  In this case, we have $f$ composed with the function $2x-g(x)$.

Comment: Aha. Perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Not a problem, let me know if anything isn't clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15068/discussion-between-sab---and-hayden).